# Autofac: How do you register a generic with multiple type arguments? Registering IGenRepo<T, TKey> with EFGenRepo<T, TKey>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5.2, .net-4.5.2

I am trying to build a generic repo and use autofac for testing. I have the following interface:

```cs
public interface IGenRepo<T, TKey> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> Items { get; }
    T find(TKey pk);
    RepoResult delete(TKey pk);
    RepoResult create(T item);
    RepoResult update(T item);
    RepoResult save();
}
```

And here is the class that implements that interface:

```cs
public class EFGenRepo<T, TKey> : IGenRepo<T, TKey> where T : class
{
    private PortalEntities context = new PortalEntities();

    public IQueryable<T> Items { get { return context.Set<T>().AsQueryable<T>(); } }

    public T find(TKey pk){}
    public RepoResult delete(TKey pk){}
    public RepoResult create(T item){}
    public RepoResult update(T item){}
    public RepoResult save(){}
    private RepoResult save(T item){}
}
```

Here's the registration I am using:

```
cb.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EFGenRepo<>)).As(typeof(IGenRepo<>));
```

The compile error I get on this line is:

> Using the generic type 'Domain.Concrete.EFGenRepo` requires 2
>   type arguments.

I haven't used autofac a lot, but when I remove the TKey generic parameter it all works fine and the error message:"**Using the generic type 'Domain.Concrete.EFGenRepo'requires 2 type arguments**" is gone...while still using the T parameter...Can somebody tell me how to set it up correctly, prefering not to change my IGenRepo interface and EFGenRepo class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
RegisterGeneric(typeof(EFGenRepo<,>)).As(typeof(IGenRepo<,>));
```